# Data source is an invalid type. It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource

Tags: c#, gridview

Data source is an invalid type. It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource. The error is displayed when I bind the grid view

```
var list = dal.GetEmployeebyName(name);
GridViewEmployee.DataSource = list;
GridViewEmployee.DataBind();
```

i have the query

```
public EmployeeInfo GetEmployeebyName(String name)
{
    using (var context = new HRMSEntities())
    {
        return context.EmployeeInfo.FirstOrDefault(e => e.FName == name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use a `GridView` to display just 1 record?

Answer (score 5):

You are returning a single object from GetEmployeebyName method and binding that to the GridViewEmployee, thats why it is giving error.

You can change it like

```
var empInfo = dal.GetEmployeebyName(name);
var list = new List<EmployeeInfo>{empInfo};

//or you can do this 
//var list = new List<EmployeeInfo>();
//list.Add(empInfo);

GridViewEmployee.DataSource = list;
GridViewEmployee.DataBind();
```

DataSource must be a type of collection as the exception is stating ( It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource)

Comment: I think it should be `var list = new List<EmployeeInfo>() { empInfo };` Mind the braces.

Comment: Yes, It can be, but it will also work `var list = new List<EmployeeInfo>{empInfo};`

Comment: interesting, I must say I never tried it your way, so perhaps it does. :)

Answer (score 1):

Could the above not be shortend to..

```
var empInfo = dal.GetEmployeebyName(name);

GridViewEmployee.DataSource = empInfo.ToList();
GridViewEmployee.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my testing page I make us of the following piece of code to display a list of different objects or just a single object in the same gridview.

```
   var data = bl.getAirlines();
   // If single object returned cast to List
   // Note that could be already a list of 1 item though!
    if (data.Count == 1)
    {
        var list = new List<object> { data };               
        GridView1.DataSource = list;
    }
    else
     // Bind to list of items returned
        GridView1.DataSource = data;

    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Hope it helps! It works for me :)