# Additional information: Data source is an invalid type. It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I m trying to retrieve and display user data from database based on CustomerID. I get above error while executing.
Here is my code to display data.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            int customerID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["CustomerID"]);
            MyProfileGridView.DataSource = CustomerBL.GetCustomer(customerID);
            MyProfileGridView.DataBind(); 
        }
    }
```

Get Customer Method code:

```
public static Customer GetCustomer(int customerID)
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE [CustomerID] = @CustomerID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customerID;

        DataTable dt = DbUtility.GetRecordsInDataTable(cmd);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            customer.CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["CustomerID"]);
            customer.LoginID = dt.Rows[0]["LoginID"].ToString();
            customer.Password = dt.Rows[0]["Password"].ToString();
            customer.CustomerName = dt.Rows[0]["CustomerName"].ToString();
            customer.ShopName = dt.Rows[0]["ShopName"].ToString();
            customer.Address = dt.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
            customer.Mobile1 = dt.Rows[0]["Mobile1"].ToString();
            customer.Mobile2 = dt.Rows[0]["Mobile2"].ToString();
            customer.ReferenceNumber = dt.Rows[0]["ReferenceNumber"].ToString();
            customer.SignUpDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["SignUpDate"]);
            customer.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[0]["Enabled"]);
            return customer;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

User SignUp Page code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int customerID;

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["CustomerID"] != null)
            {

                customerID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["CustomerID"]);

                Customer customer = CustomerBL.GetCustomer(customerID);

                if (customer != null)
                {
                    LoginIdLabel.Text = customer.LoginID;
                    PasswordLabel.Text = customer.Password;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Error   8   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<******.Entities.Customer>' to '******.Entities.Customer' C:\Users*****\Desktop\New folder*******\UserSignUpSuccess.aspx.cs  25  41  ******

Kindly help me to solve this issue

Comment: Have had a look at these similar SO questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754104/data-source-is-an-invalid-type-it-must-be-either-an-ilistsource-ienumerable-o) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535023/data-source-is-an-invalid-type-it-must-be-either-an-ilistsource-ienumerable-o)

Comment: Such an error would generate if you are trying to bind to a single object when you need a collection or `IEnumerable`. Please check out the answers to the questions mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error is clear enough you need to assign `List<Customer>` to `DataSource`. `DataSource` can't be assigned with a `single object`.

You need to return `List<Customer>` from `GetCustomer` method and assign to `DataSource`.

```
public static List<Customer> GetCustomer(int customerID)
{
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE [CustomerID] = @CustomerID";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customerID;

    DataTable dt = DbUtility.GetRecordsInDataTable(cmd);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        customer.CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["CustomerID"]);
        customer.LoginID = dt.Rows[0]["LoginID"].ToString();
        customer.Password = dt.Rows[0]["Password"].ToString();
        customer.CustomerName = dt.Rows[0]["CustomerName"].ToString();
        customer.ShopName = dt.Rows[0]["ShopName"].ToString();
        customer.Address = dt.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
        customer.Mobile1 = dt.Rows[0]["Mobile1"].ToString();
        customer.Mobile2 = dt.Rows[0]["Mobile2"].ToString();
        customer.ReferenceNumber = dt.Rows[0]["ReferenceNumber"].ToString();
        customer.SignUpDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["SignUpDate"]);
        customer.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[0]["Enabled"]);
        list.Add(customer);            
        return list;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Your `GetCustomer` method return List` so you need to get object from list to access its properties.

```
Customer customer = CustomerBL.GetCustomer(customerID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I am receiving this error. Error 8 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<******.Entities.Customer>' to '******.Entities.Customer' C:\Users\*****\Desktop\New folder\****\***\UserSignUpSuccess.aspx.cs 25 41 ******

Comment: You have not change return type of method it should be `public static List<Customer> GetCustomer(int customerID)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are inserting one and only `Customer` object to a `GridView` component which is requesting a `List` type data source. By the way if you want to add that customer object however to that  `GridView`, you can try by returning a list,

```
    public static List<Customer> GetCustomer(int customerID)
        {
            List<Customer> CusList = new List<Customer>();
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            .... // Before returning,
            CusList.Add(customer);
            return CusList;
        }
```